# Bind ISet in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, collections, binding

I am trying to find out what would be the best way to bind first element of `ISet` (`Iesi.Collection`) as a first element.

So basically I only have to use some kind of collection that has an indexer (and `ISet` doesn't) then I can write code like this (which works perfectly well):

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Company.PrimaryUsers[0].Email) %>
```

But as the ISet has no indexer I cannot use it.

So how can I then bind the first element of ISet in MVC2?

Thanks,
Dmitriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately those strongly typed helpers work only with indexer properties for collections. They would actually look for opening and closing `[` `]` brackets in the syntax.

A possible workaround would be to add another property in your view model class which would be of type `IList` and would be populated from the original property. In the getter you would simply return a new list from the original property and in the setter you would reconstruct the original set as it does not have the notion of order.

Comment: Does not sound any good? I don't want to modify the model just for the sake or rendering it in the view. Definitely better solution should exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull this off via the following:

```
<%
  int i = 0;
  foreach (var element in Model.Company.PrimaryUsers) {
    string htmlFieldName = String.Format("Company.PrimaryUsers[{0}]", i);
    %><%: Html.EditorFor(_ => element, null /* templateName */, htmlFieldName) %><%
    i++;
  }
%>
```

This particular overload of EditorFor() says "I'm going to pass you a model, but use the htmlFieldName string for the model rather than trying to deduce it from the expression."  You have to keep track of the *i* manually in this case.

Comment: This will not bind the posted data back to the model.